# How should I format a redirectUri for use with the Instagram API?

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

When I try to integrate Instagram into my iOS app, I can see the Instagram login page in my webview. However, after giving the login details, it shows an error that the `redirectUri` is not valid.

How do I create a `redirectUri` using the Instagram developer configuration page?

Is there a specific format required to create valid one? I am currently using a `redirectUri` formatted like this: `https://appnamecallback.com`

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

It has all the valid formats for `redirect_uri`

Answer (score 0):

When you modify your application's redirect_uri then don't forget to click on "Update Client" button on instagram developer console. After click on Update Client you will get to know whether your redirect_uri is valid or not. If client is updated successfully then your redirect_uri is valid and you can use that as it is to loading request for your webview with instagram url and its parameters. But if update client is not updated successfully then your redirect_uri is invalid. In this condition you can create your application's uri and use it for redirection to your application or you can use https://stackoverflow.com, https://gmail.com, etc for temperory testing purpose.